# Extensions containing the Schur cover II

Tags: gr.group-theory

Given two finite groups $G$ and $H$ such that $H$ is a perfect subgroup of $G$, does there always exist a finite solvable group $I$ such that the Schur cover of $H$ embeds into an extension of shape $I \cdot G$?

Comment: To save me trying to work out what you mean in this case, could you please make it clear what you mean by an extension of a group $A$ by a group $B$. You should really be aware of the fact that there are two different definitions, and about $50\%$ of mathematicians use each of them.

Comment: I totally agree with Derek; using diagrams instead of words will make much more people try to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Let $M$ be the Schur Multiplier of $H$ and let $W$ be the wreath product $M \wr G$ (with the regular action of $G$).
Then $W$ is an extension of the solvable group $I^G$ by $G$ (where, by an extension of $A$ by $B$, I mean a group with a normal subgroup isomorphic to $A$ with quotient isomorphic to $B$).

Now $W$ contains $M \wr H$ as a subgroup. By the Krasner–Kaloujnine embedding theorem, every extension of $M$ by $H$ embeds into $M \wr H$, and so in particular the Schur Cover of $H$ embeds into $M \wr H$ and hence into $W$.

Note that this does not depend on $G$ being finite, although of course $I$ will be infinite if $G$ is infinite. In the infinite case $W$ must be the unrestricted wreath product for the Krasner–Kaloujnine to apply.

Also, it doesn't really depend on $H$ being perfect. If not then the Schur cover is not (in general) unique, but all Schur covers embed into $W$.